# Looking for a succinct phrase meaning someone's end goal and motivation

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm having trouble locating a phrase (possibly a loan word or phrase) similar to raison d’être, that means someones reason for doing something and end goal rather than reason for being. Kinda like a MacGuffin and raison d’être rolled into one descriptive turn of phrase.

Examples of things this phrase could describe are:

- The Harrison Ford's one-armed man in *The Fugitive*(1993)
- Szechuan Sauce for Rick in *Rick and Morty* as it is described at the end of Season 3 Episode 1.
- Starting a Mars colony for Elon Musk.

Maybe mission statement would be a sufficient phrase but I don't feel that it really captures the motivating power that these kinds of end goals have.

Any ideas on a phrase or word that would fit this definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-all-and-end-all) gives this sense for **be-all and end-all**:

> *be-all and end-all* (in British English) noun informal
>
> 1. the ultimate aim or justification
>
> *to provide help for others is the be-all and end-all of this group*